# Best way to manage height of angular components to fit in screen

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am having troubles with height of my components... I have a `mat-toolbar` in a component called `app-navbar`, and I have another component called `app-sidebar`with a `mat-nav-list` (which is a side left bar menu)

I have a third component which gets both together, but this is happening:

[image]

Last item of the `nav-list` I want it at the bottom of the page, but giving 100% height to `mat-sidenav-container` component, makes it go "out" of the page, even if the content of the page has no scroll. I can have it correctly by setting it's height as: `height: calc(100% - 64px)` which 64px is height of th material toolbar (by default). I don't feel like this is a correct solution, because if material decides sometime on changing the size of the height, I will have troubles.

Is there any way using flex or similar to make it better?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <app-navbar [mySideBar]="snav" fxFlex></app-navbar>
</div>
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav autoFocus="false"
                  #snav mode="side"
                  fixedInViewPort="true"
                  [mode]="side"
                  [opened]="true">
      <app-sidebar [mySideBar]="snav"></app-sidebar>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxLayout="column">
      <!-- content -->
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

CSS:

```
mat-sidenav-container {
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

Or maybe reading height size of `mat-toolbar` instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Have you tried `fxLayout="column"` on the container and `fxFlexAlign="end"` on the element?

Comment: I didn't but I made it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally make it after trying some time with fxFlex.

Parent component (which gets both together):

```
height: 100%
display: flex;
```

And put both components inside of a `<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex=100%> <!--components--> </div>`

For `<app-navbar>` remove the `fxFlex` and give component `width: 100%`

For `<app-sidebar>`this CSS:

```
:host {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -o-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And for `<mat-sidenav-container>` give `fxFlex="100%"`

Answer (score 3):

No, I would say the calc method is the best one. That's how I do the same thing, at the very least. You can protect yourself from random material design changes somewhat by setting yourself the toolbar height. If you're using SASS, you can store the toolbar height in a variable (or a map, with the height for each media-query, if it changes), and use it both for the height in the toolbar and for the calc with `height: calc(100vh - #{$toolbar-height})`.

---

**Edit:**

Just for fun, I did a quick and dirty model with css grid. It works okay, but I'm not sure how much of it would be viable for your particular code, so the answer still stands anyway. Just an option to consider:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 64px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.toolbar {
  background:  grey;
  width:       100%;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #BAD;
}

.content {
  padding: 24px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="toolbar"></div>
  
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  
  <div class="content">
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia dolores odio consequuntur beatae? Doloribus corrupti accusantium dolore, fuga magni eaque odio perferendis autem voluptatem distinctio alias ducimus consequatur debitis dignissimos.</p>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know SASS. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark one of the answers as accepted, even if it's your own, since it helps people searching for the same thing.

Comment: I have to wait 4 more hours to be able to accept mine